# How to Combine Budget, Actual and Forecast data from multiple tables in PowerBI Desktop

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have three tables loaded into PowerBI desktop:

- BudgetExtract
- ActualExtract
- ForecastExtract

Each table has the following information:

- ProjectID
- Cost
- Month

Note that each table has multiple rows per month (e.g. Project1 could have 30 lines of costs relating to January 2023).

I need to create a line chart visual that compares the budget, actual and forecast amounts for each month, up to the final month in any of the files.

I have so far attempted to create a number of visuals by using the month column from one table (e.g. Actual Extract), then adding the cost amount for each of the three tables, but the result is that the cost total value is shown for the two tables that the month column doesn't come from, rather than a given months total.

What is the best way to get the intended result?

Relationship mode:

[image]

Comment: have you set relationship between three tables? let me see your realtionship view

Comment: @Sia - I've updated the question with a screenshot of the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want compare in line chart of MONTH so you also need set relationship for MONTH column besides PROJECT_CODE. Try below:

Create a new column in all three tables:

```
New Column = [ProjectID]&[Cost]&[Month]
```

Set relationship among these three tables with the new column.